# Php : json_encode is returning NULL array at the start of the string

Tags: php, android, mysql, dreamweaver

This is my Php code. I am new in php and I want to get proper responce of JSON.

```
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $db_handle  )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   else 
    $response["message"] = "Connected Succsessfully";
     //echo json_encode($response);


$db_found = mysql_select_db($db, $db_handle);

// check for required fields
   if($db_found)
{
    // mysql inserting a new row
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//iterate over all the rows
$emparray[] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //iterate over all the fields
       $emparray[] = $row;
}

   echo json_encode($emparray);
```

And this is my responce :

```
[[],{"id":"1","username":"Liyari","password":"Karachi"},{"id":"12","username":"ssssss","password":"111111"},{"id":"121","username":"135","password":"Qasim"},{"id":"17","username":"nafees","password":"99999"},{"id":"134","username":"","password":""},{"id":"133","username":"","password":""},{"id":"135","username":"mustafa","password":"45612"},{"id":"131","username":"mustafa","password":"45612"},{"id":"132","username":"","password":""}]
```

Q) Why I am getting null array at the start of Response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove

```
$emparray[] = array();
```

or make it as

```
$emparray = array();
```

then it will work fine.

Comment: YES i KNOW THIS IS RIGHT ANSWER AND HELP ME LOT

Answer (score 3):

When you write something like

```
$foo[] = $something;
```

in php, you are adding an element to the end of the array.

With

```
$emparray[] = array();
```

you are adding and array as first element, because `$emparray` is not previously initialized, and that's because you get an empty array at the beginning of the response.

You should change

```
$emparray[] = array();
```

by

```
$emparray = array();
```